# Tomcat 8 fails to start for Spring Boot Application from Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am making a rest application using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE, I have deployed this application in an external tomcat. The application connects to a data source defined in the server.xml and a resource link provided in context.xml. Everything works fine when I manually add the war file to tomcat's webapps folder and run it from command line. However, when I try to run the project inside STS (run as->run on server), after adding the same server to the workspace, the server fails to start up and throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

My main class is :

```
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication.class);
    }

}

    application.properties
    spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Can someone help me understand why is this? I want my code to get hot deployed when I do a save and the server to run from IDE. Even though the code runs perfectly fine when deployed manually but this does not allow me to debug the flow by putting break points. I use maven for building the war file.

**EDIT: ** Adding stack trace from server logs:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-01-15 22:46:46.212 ERROR 5304 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5292) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30bf1f39.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30bf1f39$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8301e843.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30bf1f39.dataSource(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted

2017-01-15 22:46:46.220 ERROR 5304 --- [ina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringBootWithSpringDataJPA]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringBootWithSpringDataJPA]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5292) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/postgres/springbootDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

**EDIT** Please not I am using jndi name which has been configured in tomcat. The application works fine when run standalone in tomcat server from command line.

Comment: SpringBoot has an embeded Tomcat (7), why you don't exclude it and try? This could be causing issues.

Comment: I have already given the scope of that server as provided in pom.xml. Will try removing the dependency itself.

Comment: Tried it after removing the dependency as well. Still getting the same error along with org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start. This happens only when i try to run the project on server from STS. If war is deployed manually, it runs.

Comment: sounds like a path issue, maybe in how tomcat is started, to do a remote debug for example:  Run->Debug Configurations->Remote Java application then NEW... cause it's supposed you should not add a remote server via normal way "Create a serv".

Comment: Not able to figure out why is this. Could you please elaborate? I cleared all the run configurations. Added tomcat 8 again to my workspace but still it won't start from IDE, somehow it fails to lookup the datasource that I have given and there is a org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookUpFailureException along with the other errors I mentioned. Do you think it is because of just way I have added it or do I need to make any more code changes for it to work in IDE

Comment: Hi! I am still clueless about this, can anyone help if they have encountered a similar problem before. My tomcat won't start. It always gives me bean creation exception from IDE. org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource

Comment: to do a remot debug you should do: Run->Debug Configurations->Remote Java application-> new, did you do it this way?

Comment: Yes I did. The server won't start in debug mode as well. Tried the same thing you mentioned in comments. Also, I tried importing the project in Eclipse where the same server has been added to the IDE. While other applications work, this application does not run from IDE. Always gives datasource lookup exception.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your server configuration when run from IDE does not match command line server configuration.  Spring is complaining abur lack of datasource under certain jndi name (java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS )

Comment: I am using the same server in IDE and from command line. And the war deployed to the server in webapps folder is build from the workspace by doing mvn clean install. Can't understand why it would work with manual depoyment then?

Comment: same jars do not imply same configuration.   especially in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. I did not know that once we add server to the workspace, a separate instance of the server is created in the workspace folder and that server (which is started from the IDE) runs from workspace metadata. Now, this server instance has its own config files - `server.xml` and `context.xml` - which are different from the main server installation. My workspace instance did not have the correct jndi setup, the resource link tag in `context.xml` was missing. This is the reason why spring was not able to find my jndi datasource when run from the IDE. Once I corrected everything, it worked like a charm. Thanks to a good old friend for this eye opener.

To modify your server instance at workspace level, go to `workspace`->`Servers`->`Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config`->`server.xml`/`context.xml`. This is applicable for both eclipse and spring tool suite, though I suppose with eclipse you should be able to expand the server tab to see these files. This is the server instance which you should modify when the server location is set as workspace metadata, double click on `server` to see your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In your main class add the following annotations and imports:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.RC1/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

It works for me.